# Close issue in CodePlex on a code commit

Tags: git, codeplex

With google code, you can automatically close an issue in the issue tracker by inserting a formatted comment when you commit your code:

```
Fixes issue 156 
Here's the explanation about the issue
```

I'm looking for the same feature in CodePlex.